# StackOverflowError on context

Tags: android, sqlite, android-context, sqliteopenhelper

I got a "java.lang.StackOverflowError" error.

This is the code:

```
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897): java.lang.StackOverflowError
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications.java:28)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.RejectedNotifications.<init>(RejectedNotifications.java:27)
08-30 10:34:49.528: E/AndroidRuntime(22897):    at com.silm.database.ApprovedNotifications.<init>(ApprovedNotifications
```

about the project:

Why I want to do:

I want to click on an approve button to save the notification/message to the database of approved notification/messages. But I noticed that when I click on Aprrove button, it was inserted and  when click on the Rejected button, it was also inserted in the Rejected table. So, I check if was not in the rejected table, then inserted it to the approve table. All worked fine then, but when I did the same (delete the notification from the approve and insert in the reject), then I got the StackOverFlow Error.

Here is the code generating the error:

```
public RejectedNotifications(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME_REJECTED_NOTIFICATION, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        ***approved = new ApprovedNotifications(context);***
    }
```

The other database handler for the table Approved is like the about code:

```
public ApprovedNotifications(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME_APPROVED_NOTIFICATION, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        rejected = new RejectedNotifications(context);
    }
```

Comment: You obviously have some endless recursive loop of calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a very clear infinite recursion. `ApprovedNotifications`'s constructor creates a new `RejectedNotifications`. `RejectedNotifications` constructor creates a new `ApprovedNotifications`, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You've created an infinite loop in your code.  Each time an `ApprovedNoficiations` instance is created, it creates a `RejectedNotifications` instance, which then creates another `ApprovedNotifications` instance, and so on...

The relationship between those two classes is circular.  If you want two instances to reference each other, you may need to create one first, and then pass that as a parameter to the second.